# PHP - constructor function doesn't return false

Tags: php, class, object, constructor

How can I let the `$foo` variable below know that foo should be false?

```
class foo extends fooBase{

  private
    $stuff;

  function __construct($something = false){
    if(is_int($something)) $this->stuff = &getStuff($something);
    else $this->stuff = $GLOBALS['something'];

    if(!$this->stuff) return false;
  }

}

$foo = new foo(435);  // 435 does not exist
if(!$foo) die(); // <-- doesn't work :(
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You cannot return a value from the constructor. You can use [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for that.

```
function __construct($something = false){
    if(is_int($something)) $this->stuff = &getStuff($something);
    else $this->stuff = $GLOBALS['something'];

    if (!$this->stuff) {
        throw new Exception('Foo Not Found');
    }
}
```

And in your instantiation code:

```
try {
    $foo = new foo(435);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

You can also extend exceptions.

Comment: you mean http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php ? but won't that show a php error and stop the script? I only want to return false ...

Comment: Not if you `catch` it. You can do anything you want from that point.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Instead you should assign what ever variable is given and then call  `if ( $foo->is_falid() ){ /* do stuff */}` , and please stop abusing `die()` function.

Comment: weird, you need the {} brackets in try catch even if you're writing a single statement :s

Answer (score 5):

Constructor is not supposed to return anything.

If you need to validate data before using the to create an object, you should use a factory class.

Edit: yeah , exceptions would do the trick too, but you should not have any logic inside the constructor. It becomes a pain for unit-testing.

Comment: what's a factory class and how do I use it? :D

Comment: @Alex , watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc) , this might explain some of it ( yes , the example are in java , but it's a talk about theory and not "how to write hello world" ).

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<?php

function __construct($something = false){ 
    $this->stuff = $something; 
}

static function init($something = false){
    $stuff = is_int($something) ? &getStuff($something) : $GLOBALS['something'];
    return $stuff ? new self($stuff) : false;
}


$foo = foo::init(435);  // 435 does not exist
if(!$foo) die();
```